# PSCP file from Windows to Linux using private/public keys

Tags: unix, private-key, pscp

I can transfer file using PSCP:

```
C:\>pscp -pw <password> -r -p <path of the file>  user@Server:<path file to stored>
```

But not using the public/private key.

Steps followed:

1. Generate public and private keys using PuTTYgen.
2. Copy the public key to authorized_keys of Remote Server
3. Save the private key to key.ppk in Windows server
4. Then

   ```
   C:\>pscp -i privatekey pathofthefile user@server:pathfiletostored
   ```

It gives "Fatal: Network error: Connection refused"

Can someone please help?

Comment: What are .ssh directory and authorized_keys file permissions on remote server?

Comment: Permission of .ssh is drwx_ _ _ _ __ and authorised_keys is _rw- r-- r--

Answer (score 41):

Use the following code:

```
C:\>pscp -i "path\of\the\privatekey\privatekey.ppk" C:\temp\example_file.txt user@server:/path/file/to/be/stored
```

Note the quotes for the private key path and the private key should be in .ppk format.

The connection refused error may also be due to the wrong port. In that case, you need to mention the correct port by the following code :

```
C:\>pscp -i "path\of\the\privatekey\privatekey.ppk" -P 8022 C:\temp\example_file.txt user@server:path/file/to/be/stored
```

Note that 8022 is the port number and the P is uppercase. Hope this helps.